# spring boot kafka producer disable topic auto creation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to disable the automatic topic creation for kafka producer when topic is not available.
I am using Spring Boot 2.7.6, that means spring-kafka version 2.8.11

I found similar property for Kafka consumer - **ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG** and that works fine.

I expect Spring to throw exception during message sending if topic is not available. Currently, the topic gets created automatically.

Consumer:

```
@Bean
fun kafkaConsumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String?, String?> {
    val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = bootstrapAddress
    props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = groupId
    props[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "latest"
    props[ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG] = false
    props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = ErrorHandlingDeserializer::class.java
    props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = ErrorHandlingDeserializer::class.java
    props[ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    props[ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props)
}
```

Producer:

```
@Bean
fun kafkaProducerFactory(): ProducerFactory<String?, String?> {
    val configProps: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    configProps[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = bootstrapAddress
    configProps[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
    configProps[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
    return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configProps)
}
```

Is that impossible, or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: You can use AdminClient to check topic existence and throw your own runtime exception

Comment: @Gobanit I am also facing same problem , were you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a property for Kafka producer. You have to use a Broker one: `auto.create.topics.enable`: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: Brokers typically don't create topics on the producer side; you usually get a message about meta data not found for the topic/partition, with an eventual timeout.

Comment: if I understand it right, the producer tells the broker, he wants to create a message in specific topic. And if the broker itself doesnt have the auto topic creation feature disable, it gets created. It is therefore not my responsibility (as a developer of the producer app) to handle this setting. Right?

Comment: I feel the same. As Gary said you are going to fail attempting to produce if topic is not present on the broker.

Comment: In my experiance, broker auto topic creation only occurs for consumers (based on the broker and consumer config), not for producers.